# Why rel="tooltip" and data-original-title not work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day.

I use bootstrap 3 and jquery 1.9

**Code:**

```
<span rel="tooltip" class="tir" data-original-title="Hello">
<span class="price">100</span><br>
<span class="description"><span class="bidNum">0</span> hi</span> 
</span>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("*[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Tell me please why code not work?

Where error?

Comment: Have you included `tooltip.js` ? Furthermore, upon reviewing http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips , I don't see where `data-orginal-title` is used

Comment: @JamesMohler sure, also see code button in page bootstrap 3.0 for see `data-orginal-title`

Comment: i didn't found a problem with your code. The default tooltip is on the top of the element, will this be visible in your situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code above works fine here: http://bootply.com/93035. The issue was that the tooltip was showing up off screen. Adding a `data-placement="auto"` will solve this issue.